# Change data from pointer C++

Tags: c++, function

In that intercepted function below, I have `buff` as a pointer to buffer, how can I change data without creating new my own buffer?

```
int WINAPI OwnRecv(SOCKET s, char FAR *buff, int len, int flags)
{
    if(s == ServerSocket)
    {
        int received = pTrampolineRecv(s, buff, len, flags);

        if(received <= 0)
        {
            return received;
        }

            unsigned char ReceiveBuffer[1024]; // how can i avoid creatin this by changing buff directly?
        do_decrypt((const unsigned char *) buff, ReceiveBuffer, received, KeyTest, NULL);
        buff = (char *) ReceiveBuffer;

        return received;
    }
    return pTrampolineRecv(s, buff, len, flags);
}
```

**upd**

I added my `do_decrypt` function

```
bool do_decrypt(const unsigned char *in, unsigned char *out, int inlen)
{
  int buflen, tmplen;

  if(!EVP_DecryptUpdate(&Decrypt_ctx, out, &buflen, in, inlen))
  {
        return false;
  }

  if(!EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(&Decrypt_ctx, out + buflen, &tmplen))
    {
        return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to change data in `buff`?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve here?  That is, why are to trying to avoid the creation of a buffer on the stack?

Comment: You're passing unitialized ``int bufflen`` to ``EVP_DecryptUpdate`` which probably expects output buffer lenght. Roman, you need to take basic C++ lessons instead of asking questions on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely take a look at C++ tutorial about pointers before jumping straight on WinAPI code.

Also, FAR keyword is deprecated.

The simplest idea would be

```
do_decrypt ((const unsigned char*) buff, (unsigned char *) buff, received, KeyTest, NULL);
```

So basically - putting `buff` as both input and output variable.

But I DO NOT recommend using it, as I don't know how `do_decrypt` function works - you might end messing up your own data when decrypting. Only use above if do_decrypt is using some sort of (possibly smaller) internal buffer.

Maybe try to clarify the question a bit more, as now I won't be able to give you any more advice on the question.

EDIT: So, thanks to other answers, you can use solution above when:

1. Result data will fit in the input buffer (size of output <= size of input)
2. `do_decrypt` function allows *in situ* operation - thus, modyfing data that's being read.

Comment: i added my code of do_decrypt function, but i dont know if this function allows input-output buffers ((

Comment: It's still using other functions, so we know nothing about it's behavior. You gotta look at documentation about these `EVP_...` functions and check there.

Answer (score 1):

If `do_decrypt` does not preclude it, just pass in `buff` as the second param on the call, with appropriate casting to make this 'work' (compile).

```
do_decrypt((const unsigned char *) buff, buff, received, KeyTest, NULL);
```

This means your input and output buffers are the same, which may be problematic in the called function.

You also need to be sure in this case (and in any case) that you have enough space in the output buffer to hold the decrypted data, or a buffer overrun will occur and you will be in big trouble.  For example - in your code, imagine that there are 2048 bytes instead of 1024.  Seems like you should be (assuming decryption does not change the data length) allowing for `received` characters in `ReceiveBuffer.

Your assignment of `ReceiveBuffer` to `buff` has only local scope: the caller will not see this change.  DoIng this would in any case make using the function quite confusing, since it might or might not change the input value.

Answer (score 0):

If Bartek's answer doesn't work -- i.e., if `do_decrypt` doesn't support using the same buffer for both input and output -- then you'll need to copy the data from `ReceiveBuffer` into `buff`, probably using either `strcpy` (if it's null-terminated) or `memcpy` (if not).